# Admob no space to show ads:

Tags: admob

I took at a look at some of the similar examples related to the same problem but the reason I am posting this is because I couldn't find any answers unique to my case.

This is my layout for one of the views:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#CEFAC6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- android:background="@drawable/search" -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/search" />
           <!--android:onClick="onClick1"-->


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"    
        android:ems="10"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/song_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/search_song" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tune_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_tune" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_item" />
    </RadioGroup>

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4360034453907355/2264488829"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"                         
                         />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using a test ad and its actually displaying in the fragment in the bottom but then I see this error in my logcat logs.

W/Ads     (28664): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 960x150, but only has 960x0

EDIT: I get this only when I click on the Edit Text element and not anytime else.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your xml. Try doing a clean build. Sometimes you can accumulate config that will cause extraneous layout issues like this.

Comment: I found out it just happens because the textedit shows the keyboard which covers the ad. . IT has not caused any issues so far but I am not sure if it might lead to real problems